# Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a javascript class which is using `requirejs` I have created a constructor to create instances of this, also with methods as follows

```
define(function() {

    function Websocket(socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.ws = new Websocket('ws://localhost:'.concat(socket));
        this.ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    }

    // WebSocket event handlers
    Websocket.ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Open");
        // Sends a JSON encoded message
        Websocket.ws.sendcmd("sum",2,3);
    };


    return Websocket

});
```

But whenever I do this, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onopen' of undefined`. I'm not sure what the problem is, as Websocket seems defined to me, as shown by the constructor. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Websocket` is defined as a function, but never called, so `Websocket.ws` *isn't* defined.

Comment: And wouldn't be even if it *had* been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a disconnect between the constructor and instance of `Websocket`, which is causing your problem.

If you want to assign to a particular `Websocket`'s `ws`, you need to do that after the `Websocket` and corresponding `ws` have been created. That will typically be within the constructor, after you've assigned `this.ws`.

However, in your example, the `Websocket` constructor is recursive and should cause a stack overflow. Every time you create a socket, you will create another within it, causing an infinitely deep tree of sockets. This probably isn't what you want, and I would suggest renaming your `Websocket` function(/constructor) to something with a unique name (perhaps `SocketWrapper`).

If you wanted all `Websocket`s to have an `onopen` property, you should use the `Websocket.prototype.onopen` syntax. This creates (and assigns) a property to the prototype of `Websocket`, so all `new Websocket`s will have that property. This does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `ws` is not a property of your `Websocket` constructor. Inside your constructor function, you want `this.ws.onopen = funciton() { ... }`